# Buffer overflow when I sort records by Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Buffer overflow when I sort records by Pymongo. I want to sort the records only satisfied certain location by time1. But I got Overflow.

```
>>> records = db['LOG'].find({"location":"172.27.112.18"}).sort('time1', 1)
>>> for i in records:
...     nill.append(i)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1090, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1012, in _refresh
    self.__read_concern))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 903, in __send_message
    codec_options=self.__codec_options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 137, in _unpack_response
    error_object)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: Plan executor error during find: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554525 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting on a field for which an index doesn't exist. 
In this case there exists a limit of ~ 32 MB 
(see [sort operations here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Sorted-Documents)) 
To resolve the issue create an index on 'time1' as :

```
db.LOG.create_index([('time1', 1)])
```